# wxFlexGridSizer AddGrowableCol throwing error

Tags: wxwidgets

I have several wxFlexGridSizers that used to work in wxWigets version 2.8.11. After upgrading the wxWidgets library to 2.9.4 I am now getting an invalid column index in wxFlexGridSizer::AddGrowableCol().

Here is a sample of the sizer that I am creating:

```
wxFlexGridSizer* fgSizer1;
fgSizer1 = new wxFlexGridSizer( 3, 2, 0, 0 );
fgSizer1->AddGrowableCol( 2 );
fgSizer1->SetFlexibleDirection( wxBOTH );
fgSizer1->SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wxFLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED );
```

I tried changing the value of the AddGrowableCol() arguement to 1 because maybe I thought it might have been wrong before or something but it still throws the same error. I can include the stacktrace if that would be helpful as well.

```
..\..\src\common\sizer.cpp(1956): assert "!m_cols || idx < (size_t)m_cols" failed in wxFlexGridSizer::AddGrowableCol(): invalid column index

Call stack:
[00] wxGUIAppTraitsBase::ShowAssertDialog       j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\common\appcmn.cpp:475
[01] ShowAssertDialog                           j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\common\appbase.cpp:1265
[02] wxAppConsoleBase::OnAssertFailure          j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\common\appbase.cpp:761
[03] wxDefaultAssertHandler                     j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\common\appbase.cpp:1065
[04] wxOnAssert                                 j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\common\appbase.cpp:1141
[05] wxFlexGridSizer::AddGrowableCol            j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\common\sizer.cpp:1956
[06] MyFrame::MyFrame                           c:\users\james\documents\code\wx29starter - copy (2)\minimal.cpp:181
[07] MyApp::OnInit                              c:\users\james\documents\code\wx29starter - copy (2)\minimal.cpp:130
[08] wxAppConsoleBase::CallOnInit               j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\include\wx\app.h:94
[09] wxEntryReal                                j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\common\init.cpp:456
[10] wxEntry                                    j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\msw\main.cpp:189
[11] wxEntry                                    j:\wxwidgets-2.9.4\src\msw\main.cpp:416
[12] WinMain                                    c:\users\james\documents\code\wx29starter - copy (2)\minimal.cpp:111
[13] __tmainCRTStartup                          f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c:578
[14] WinMainCRTStartup                          f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c:403
[15] BaseThreadInitThunk                     
[16] RtlInitializeExceptionChain             
[17] RtlInitializeExceptionChain
```

Here is the assert code

```
void wxFlexGridSizer::AddGrowableCol( size_t idx, int proportion )
{
    wxASSERT_MSG( !IsColGrowable( idx ),
                  "AddGrowableCol() called for growable column" );

    // see comment in AddGrowableRow(): although it's less common to omit the
    // specification of the number of columns, it still can also happen
    wxCHECK_RET( !m_cols || idx < (size_t)m_cols, "invalid column index" );

    m_growableCols.Add( idx );
    m_growableColsProportions.Add( proportion );
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me if I change the parameter to 1 for the call to AddGrowableCol().  Please try that test again - perhaps you messed somerthing up.

Comment: `AddGrowableCol()` is zero indexed and the four argument override of `wxFlexGridSizer` is defined as `(int rows, int cols, int vgap, int hgap)` - so you are trying to set the third column as growable in a two column layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With confirmation from  winterblood changing the parameter to 1 for the call to AddGrowableCol()will solve the problem, despite your test!

Comment: You are right. It was throwing it from another one. Thanks for your help. Any idea why this worked in the older version?

Comment: Presumably the assert was missing or miscoded and then fixed in the new release.